# Como obter a soma de uma coluna BigDecimal

Tags: java, mysql

Preciso somar uma coluna de dados `BigDecimal` do MySQL, que já foi filtrada de um dado intervalo. Estou tentando com `SELECT SUM(preco_total) FROM venda;` no código abaixo, mas não estou conseguindo resultados.

Aqui estão os meus códigos:

Estrutura da tabela `venda`:

```
> `DESCRIBE venda;`
+-----------------+---------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field           | Type          | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-----------------+---------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| codigo          | bigint(20)    | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| bairro          | varchar(50)   | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| cep             | varchar(30)   | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| cidade          | varchar(30)   | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| complemento     | varchar(30)   | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| estado          | varchar(2)    | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| horario         | datetime      | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| logradouro      | varchar(40)   | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| nome_cliente    | varchar(80)   | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| preco_total     | decimal(10,2) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| vendedor_codigo | bigint(20)    | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
+-----------------+---------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
11 rows in set (0.01 sec)
```

O meu código `vendaBean`:

```
public void soma() {
        try {
            VendaDAO vendaDAO = new VendaDAO();
            vendaDAO.soma();

        } catch (RuntimeException erro) {
            Messages.addGlobalError("Não foi possível exibir a soma. Contate o Suporte.");
        }
    }

}
```

Abaixo, o meu código `vendaDAO`;

```
public List<Venda> soma() {
        List<Venda> vendas = null;
        Session sessao = HibernateUtil.getFabricaDeSessoes().openSession();
        try {
            StringBuilder sql = new StringBuilder();
            sql.append("SELECT SUM(preco_total) FROM venda ");

        } catch (RuntimeException erro) {
            throw erro;
        } finally {
            sessao.close();
        }
        return vendas;
    }

}
```

E por último o meu código `venda.xhtml`:

```
<p:outputLabel value="Total: R$" />
                <h:outputText value="#{vendaBean.soma()}">
                    <f:convertNumber locale="pt_BR"                     minFractionDigits="2" />
                </h:outputText>
```

Comment: No `VendaDao` você cria a query mas não executa, é isso mesmo ou ficou faltando colocar esse código? Além disso, se o método `soma` vai retornar um número (a soma dos preços), o retorno dele não deveria ser uma lista.  E no `VendaBean`, o método `soma` é `void` (não retorna nenhum valor), então nada será impresso no xhtml.

Comment: Ok. Muito obrigado vou consertar. Faltou executar a query? Você poderia me dar uma dica por favor? Esse é o primeiro código para somar uma coluna já previamente filtrada que eu estou desenvolvendo.

Comment: Vc criou a `Session` e o `StringBuilder` com a query, é só [juntar um com o outro](https://www.journaldev.com/3422/hibernate-native-sql-query-example) <- esse link tem alguns exemplos, mas se não sabe como executar uma query e pegar o resultado, eu sugiro procurar por tutoriais de Hibernate (no Google, já que pedidos de tutoriais **neste** site são fora do escopo). Se depois de ler os tutoriais, tentar e não conseguir e tiver alguma dúvida mais específica, você pode voltar aqui e [edit] a pergunta, detalhando sua nova dificuldade

Comment: Muito grato pela dica vou fazer como você disse.

Comment: Retornei [sua edição](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/revisions/367751/5) para a [Revisão 4](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/revisions/367751/4), pois sua ultima edição deletou toda a pergunta e a deixou com **qualidade muito baixa**.